# Points snap back when editing polygons

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, leaflet.draw

We have a web app that uses MapBox.

In the Leaflet control we're drawing polygons in a feature group, laid over a basemap.

What we're seeing is that for certain polygons, when we try to edit the polygon, when we drag points they snap right back to where they were.

Other polygons on the same map can be edited without issue.

I've attached an animated GIF that shows the behavior.

This is something that seems to be going on entirely within the Leaflat Javascript code, and I'm at a loss as to how to track it down.

I certainly don't expect anyone to be able to identify what I'm doing wrong, or what might be wrong within the Leaflet library, from as sketchy a report as this.
[image]
But I was hoping someone might be able to provide me with some guidance as to where I might start?

Specifically, if I was to try to walk through the javascript in a debugger, where should I put my breakpoints?

I've downloaded the uncompressed mapbox source, and I'm able to set breakpoints in it, but I've been unable to find which code executes on mouseup, in this situation.

Comment: Please provide more information: can you provide a jsFiddle as an example, or a link to a page, or a code snippet?

Comment: The problem is very much data-related. Certain polygons show problems, others don't. It's not something I can replicate in a simple example. What I'm looking for is some insight on where to start debugging this.